# identity column increment set to 0

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment, identity-column

What advantage do you get in SQL Server by creating an Identity column like:

```
ID INT IDENTITY(9,0)
```

Note there is no NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY, or UNIQUE constraint or UNIQUE index, so there is no bar to doing this.  Doesn't this give every new column the same seed number and never increment it? To what end?

Comment: This would place the same int in every record. IMO if you ever need to do this, you are missing a more obvious/correct solution. Just because you *can* do `IDENTITY(X, 0)` doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: I know.  That's why I'm trying to figure out why somebody did it in a database (in every table) in a system I'm just inheriting.

Comment: Aside from this being strange it is a good indication there are some other major problems with that table. Sounds painful that no tables have a primary key. What a nightmare.

Comment: Prepare 3 envelopes. http://www.notboring.com/jokes/work/3.htm

Comment: I just am curious whether this is purposeful in some obscure way to the db designer, or if s/he just mistakenly thought you HAD to have an IDENTITY column in a table, but didn't ever expect to use the ID column so he set it to not increment.   If there IS an obscure reason for this, I don't want to screw up something he is depending on.

Comment: Check the code and see if the columns are being used and, if so, how they are being used. I can think of no sane reason to do an identity that way, but maybe they were more clever than me. Very unlikely though :P

Comment: In every table? Hopefully it's (somehow) vestigial. Otherwise: seconding "run for the hills".

Comment: A certain percentage of developers are idiots. Don't make the mistake of assuming that what the other person did was rational. Just fix it and move on.

Comment: I've been doing this for 40 years and have written code in a dozen languages and using just about every RDBMS and have never seen it.  Two things come to mind.  Either he didn't understand priimary key unique columns or he was confusing the initializing of the incrementation with the way you parameterize a real numeric - numeral(9,0).  Either way, with over 100 tables and masses of legacy code, a code search will be problematic.  I'm going to ignore it and see if any problems crop up post mortem. The rest of the code isn't the work of a 10x programmer either.  Thanks all for the commenting.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? From SQL Server 2005 and up I get an error trying to do that "Identity column 'ID' contains invalid INCREMENT.".

Answer (score 0):

Why is like that? It will allways set 9 to every row... Change that and it should have a unique constraint or primary key or a sequence (this if its SQL server 2012)